# What is the meaning of $Loop = @()

Tags: powershell, for-loop

In a script I work with I ran into this loop:

```
$Loop = @()
$loopCount = 100
for($i=1;$i -le $loopCount;$i++)
{
    #statements
}
```

I can't figure out what is the purpose of the first line `$Loop = @()` $Loop is not mentioned anywhere else in the loop or in the script.

I know what the statement does, and I also understand the PowerShell naming convention as well as how arrays work. But, does it have an actual purpose in this script for the loop itself? Or is it just old code which wasn't removed?

My question is strictly related to if this is a PowerShell hardcoded variable or not, similar to `$true` or `$false`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@()` denotes an empty array.

`$Loop = @()` means an empty array is assigned into a variabled called `$Loop`.

If `$Loop` is not used, yes, it could be old code that you are dealing with.

Comment: It also means that someone needs more descriptive variable names. :)

Comment: @EBGreen: It could have been just `$Variable`, so not the worst pick ever. :)

Comment: I know what the statement does, but I don't know if it's some sort of requirement for PowerShell or not.

Comment: @slybloty: Requirement for Powershell? What do you mean? You can be creative with the variable name. Whatever is in the loop does not need to start with `Loop`. You don't need to declare a `$Loop` variable before you start a loop.

Comment: @Neolisk I'm not asking about the naming of the variables. I just want to know if this is some sort of needed statement for loops with PowerShell. I've edited the question hoping it better reflects my intent.

Comment: @slybloty: No, it's not a reserved word in Powershell, if that's what you mean. Actually, try removing this line and see if behavior of your script changes. This is how you can troubleshoot any code written in any language.

Comment: I have removed the line and seen no change. But I wanted to ensure this wasn't anything specific to PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

As Neolisk explained, there's no special significance to naming a variable 'loop' and `$loop = @()` doesn't do much for the code you posted, because `$loop` isn't used again there.

Creating an empty array variable can be useful in other cases. For instance, this returns `hihowdy`:

```
$loopy = "hi"
$loopy += "howdy"
$loopy
```

and this returns an array with elements, `hi` and `howdy`:

```
$loopy = @()
$loopy += "hi"
$loopy += "howdy"
$loopy
```

...and this uses memory more efficiently:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$loopy = "hi"
$loopy.Add("hi")
$loopy.Add("howdy")
$loopy
```

Comment: I'm not asking about the naming. I'm asking if that statement/variable is needed or not.

Comment: Every time you use `+=` with arrays, you are recreating an array from scratch. Consider using lists for better memory management, or hash  tables `@{}`. In this case (above example), of course, the difference will be negligible.

Comment: +1. Not that I am a big fan of ArrayList class, but it should serve the purpose in this example.